# What is the use of onChildTitleChanged(Activity childActivity, CharSequence title) in android?

Tags: android

What is the actual use of onChildTitleChanged(Activity childActivity, CharSequence title) method in android,Any explanation would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This probably refers to child Activities (as in the case of the old `TabHost` and `TabWidget` classes, which are deprecated and should not be used). In general you shouldn't have to worry about this.